# tkinter How I can set position of label using pack()

Tags: python, tkinter

how I can set position of label using .pack()?

I want make something such this:

```
Label(root, text ="Text").pack(x=100, y=100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.pack()` method does not set position for any tkinter object , use `.grid()` with the arguments bieng `(row=,column=`).
this will help you set the position of an object

Answer (score 0):

pack() is only designed to organize geometry vertically. It looks like you're looking for grid() and/or setting object sizes carefully when making the objects. If you're dead-set on using pack(), you can pack a frame and grid objects within it.

Comment: _"pack() is only designed to organize geometry vertically."_ - that's not exactly true. It's also very good at organizing widgets horizontally.

Comment: `pack()` is certainly not designed for only organizing geometry vertically, it is very possible to pack widgets left to right and right to left and it very easy to center stuff and other things, so that part of the answer I would consider not correct

Answer (score 0):

you can it with `side=left/right/bottom/top` but in some situation you need to change your widets positon or you can use `before or after` in the `pack-manager`. in some situations, the `place-manager` is maybe better, if you want specific postions

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x700")

frame1 = Frame(root, bg="blue")
frame1.pack(fill="x", pady=20, ipady=20)        # fill = x, y or "both" // pady = down from the titlebar // ipady or ipadx =
                                                #  = the height of a widget

frame2 = Frame(root, bg="red")
frame2.pack(side="left", fill="y", ipadx=20)   # side = left, top, bottom, right // there also an expand function, that you can
                                               # use it with expand=true/false, expand="yes"/"no" etc....

mainloop()
```